# If 2 cells from a row is true then print another cell from that row

Tags: excel

Hard to explain in the titel

But if i have +150 rows with players.

```
[ ] [A: Name][B: Team][C: Rank][D: Leader]
[1] James - 1 - 2
[2] John - 1 - 1
[3] Albert - 1 - 3
[4] Michael - 2 - 2
[5] Eric - 2 - 1
```

Now there is no data in the column D.

I would like a form, which prints, the name of the leader of the team (Rank 1)

So in D1 = Name (Ax) where Bx = B1 and Cx = 1. ---> D1 = John, because B2 = B1 and C2 = 1.

So in D2 = Name (Ax) where Bx = B2 and Cx = 1. ---> D2 = John, because B2 = B2 and C2 = 1.

So in D3 = Name (Ax) where Bx = B3 and Cx = 1. ---> D1 = John, because B2 = B3 and C2 = 1.

So in D4 = Name (Ax) where Bx = B4 and Cx = 1. ---> D4 = Eric, because B5 = B4 and C5 = 1.

So in D5 = Name (Ax) where Bx = B5 and Cx = 1. ---> D5 = Eric, because B5 = B5 and C5 = 1.

```
[ ] [A: Name][B: Team][C: Rank][D: Leader]
[1] James - 1 - 2 - John
[2] John - 1 - 1 - John
[3] Albert - 1 - 3 - John
[4] Michael - 2 - 2 - Eric
[5] Eric - 2 - 1 - Eric
```

Comment: This is pretty confusing to follow and also inconsistent with your title. Your title implies the conditions and outputs are all within one row, but your outputs here are from rows 2 and 5. Try to explain it another way? Chances are this is a simple formula solution, which tend to be answered quickly here, and i'm guessing the reason it hasn't been answered yet is due to confusion on what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use Aggregate to find the minimum row number matching the conditions then Index to find the corresponding name:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:$A10)/((C$1:C$10=1)*(B$1:B$10=B2)),1))
```

Change the ranges to suit the number of rows that you have.